# set data function in codeigniter is not working?

Tags: json, codeigniter, web-services

Currently i am trying to make a web api for register users, so i have to encode data through **json** , but the following function is not working in the controller,

**$this->form_validation->set_data($data);**

i have the codeigniter version 2.2 , when i see its users guide, i can't find  method (i.e set_data), but it is available in  the v 3x of the codeigniter, does anyone have any suggestions regarding this so that so that i can validate the fields.

-Thank you in advance

Comment: i suppose upgrading isn't an option?

Comment: you could try removing the form validation library and replacing it with the one with v3 and thus all the methods of v3 will be available. i think most of ci's libraries are pretty loosely coupled, so there might not even be any dependencies. you might have to replace some of the helper function such as `set_value`.